# Question when reusing client in testing with symfony, differences between self and static

Tags: php, symfony, oop, phpunit

I'm following a tutorial about TDD in symfony, the tutorial is reusing the same client in every request, and he does the following way:

```
private static ?KernelBrowser $client = null;

public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();
    if(self::$client === null){
        self::$client = static::createClient();
    }
}
```

The question is why is he using a private and static property and not a simple one.

Why is not possible to do this way?

```
private ?KernelBrowser $client = null;

public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();
    if($this->client === null){
        $this->client = static::createClient();
    }
}
```

I tried the second one and I get one new instance of client every time

Comment: This code is in tests isn'it?

Comment: @qdequippe yes, this is all in a test class.

Comment: Static properties exist in the global memory space. Instance properties only start existing when the class is instantiated.

Comment: @yivi thanks for your answer. It means that each test (each method of the full test class), when its executed, gets a new instance of the full test class?

Comment: With your changed code, `client` will have to be initialized each time. With the original code, it's initialized only once per "run". You should familiarize a bit more with the "basics" of the language, as what static properties/methods/variables are, and how do they behave.

Comment: @yivi When you execute a full test class with different method tests, each test executed requires a new brand class instance?